# The "edit" button pictogram

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'd like to ask you, where can I find the system picture for "edit" like here:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the character named as `kPencilLeftUnicode` in Carbon's Events.h header: 

Answer (score 2):

The [Apple HIG lists the system-provided icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIcons/XHIGIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-SW15), but it doesn't look like that one is included.

Comment: Right, but there is no (or at least similar) icon for "edit". Or else? ,)

Answer (score 0):

Go into `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/` and right-click on `Network.prefPane`, select "Show Package Contents". Navigate in the new window into `Contents/Resources` and copy edit.tiff and editPressed.tiff whereever you want. Be aware that - of course - you should not "steal" this Image.